# Describe homeomorphism $\operatorname{Spec} A_1 \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} A_2 \sqcup \dots \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} A_n \to \operatorname{Spec} A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> If $A = A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_n$, describe a homeomorphism $\operatorname{Spec} A_1 \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} A_2 \sqcup \dots \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} A_n \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ for which each $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ is mapped onto a distinguished open subset $D(f_i)$ of $\operatorname{Spec} A$.

If we define a map $\varphi$ $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Spec} A_1 \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} A_2 \sqcup \dots \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} A_n & \to \operatorname{Spec} A \\ (\mathfrak{p}, i) &\mapsto A_1 \times \dots \times A_{i-1} \times \mathfrak{p} \times A_{i+1} \times \dots \times A_n\end{align*}$$

then I think this would be the map. It's quite clearly bijective and the inverse is pretty simple to describesi I only need to show it and the inverse are continuous.

If we consider a closed set $V(I_1 \times \dots \times I_n)$, then $$\varphi^{-1}(V(I_1 \times \dots \times I_n)) = \{(\mathfrak{p},i) \mid \varphi(\mathfrak{p},i) \in V(I_1 \times \dots \times I_n) \}$$

but the condition is equivalent to $I_1 \times \dots \times I_n \subset \varphi(\mathfrak{p},i)$ so is this a closed set?

Lastly how should we describe these $D(f_i)'s$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is correct. Let us prove the rest:

Let $f_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)\in A$ where the $1$ is at the $i$-th component. Then $\varphi(\operatorname{Spec}A_i)=D(f_i)$. Indeed, $\varphi(\mathfrak{p},i)$ doesn't contain $f_i$, and if a prime ideal of $A$ doesn't contain $f_i$ then the unique non-trivial factor has to be at the $i$-th component.

In particular, we see that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the disjoint union of the open sets $\{D(f_i)\}_i$, and thus $\varphi$ is just the disjoint union of the maps
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi_i:\operatorname{Spec} A_i&\to D(f_i)\\
\mathfrak{p}&\mapsto A_1\times\cdots\times A_{i-1}\times\mathfrak{p}\times A_{i+1}\times\cdots\times A_n
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, to show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, it suffices to show that each $\varphi_i$ is a homeomorphism. This is straightforward to see.

Edit:

Note that $\varphi_i$ is a homeomorphism. Indeed, note that we have the isomorphism $A_{f_i}\cong A_i$, and $\operatorname{Spec} A_{f_i}\cong D(f_i)$. Writing out these maps, you obtain precisely $\varphi_i$.

Now to see that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, take an open set $U\subseteq \operatorname{Spec}A_1\sqcup\cdots\sqcup \operatorname{Spec}A_n$, and write $U_i=U\cap \operatorname{Spec}A_i$. Then
$$
\varphi(U)=\varphi\left(\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}U_i\right)=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}\varphi_i(U_i)
$$
which is open as every $\varphi_i(U_i)$ is. For the reverse direction, take $V\subseteq\operatorname{Spec}A$ open, $V_i:=V\cap D(f_i)$, and then
$$
\varphi^{-1}(V)=\varphi^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}V_i\right)=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}\varphi^{-1}_i(V_i).
$$

Comment: I'm having issues with the continuity. How can we show that? @imtrying46

Comment: @Jonathan Do you see why each $\varphi_i$ is a homeomorphism? And then, do you see why this implies that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism? I made an edit.

Comment: @Jonathan Do you see now how to prove continuity, or is there still something unclear?